# Implementing facebook login in android

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook Login in my app. When the user logs in i want to retrieve the user deatils and display it to the user and save it in shared preference as well.

Login.java

```
 //Facebook Login
    mFbLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mLoginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    mCallbackManager  = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mFbLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(SocialLogin.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

            mLoginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            // TODO
                            String personName = "public_profile";
                            String personEmail = "email";
                            mSharePref.saveISLogged_IN(true);
                            mSharePref.setUserName(personName);
                            mSharePref.setEmail(personEmail);

                          //  Toast.makeText(this, mSharePref.getUserName()+""+mSharePref.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(SocialLogin.this, "Fb Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            redirectToHome();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            Toast.makeText(SocialLogin.this, "Fb Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(SocialLogin.this, "Fb Login Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: @jaydroider The problem is user is able to login via facebook. But i am unable to save the details of the user logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this error:

> Log in attempt failed: FacebookActivity could not be started

Please make sure you added `FacebookActivity` to the `AndroidManifest`.